# How to restore cache after ignite server reconnected

Tags: ignite

Really appreciate if someone can help me out.

I have an ignite server written in Java, and have a client written in C#, the client can be connected to the server, and can get server's cache correctly.
once the server restarted, the client received the EVT_CLIENT_NODE_RECONNECTED event from server. But the cache cannot be used any more.

Server code:

```
CacheConfiguration cacheConfiguration = new CacheConfiguration();

    cacheConfiguration.setName("Sample");
    cacheConfiguration.setCacheMode(CacheMode.REPLICATED);
    cacheConfiguration.setAtomicityMode(CacheAtomicityMode.ATOMIC);
    cacheConfiguration.setRebalanceMode(CacheRebalanceMode.ASYNC);
    cacheConfiguration.setWriteSynchronizationMode(CacheWriteSynchronizationMode.FULL_SYNC);
    cacheConfiguration.setBackups(0);
    cacheConfiguration.setCopyOnRead(true);
    cacheConfiguration.setStoreKeepBinary(false);

    cacheConfiguration.setReadThrough(false);
    cacheConfiguration.setWriteThrough(true);
    cacheConfiguration.setWriteBehindEnabled(true);
    cacheConfiguration.setWriteBehindFlushFrequency(2000);
    cacheConfiguration.setWriteBehindFlushThreadCount(2);

    DriverManagerDataSource theDataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    theDataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    theDataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://192.168.224.128:5432/sample");
    theDataSource.setUsername("postgres");
    theDataSource.setPassword("password");


    CacheJdbcPojoStoreFactory jdbcPojoStoreFactory = new CacheJdbcPojoStoreFactory<Long, SampleModel>()
            .setParallelLoadCacheMinimumThreshold(0)
            .setMaximumPoolSize(1)
            .setDataSource(theDataSource);

    cacheConfiguration.setCacheStoreFactory(jdbcPojoStoreFactory);


    Collection<JdbcType> jdbcTypes = new ArrayList<JdbcType>();

    JdbcType jdbcType = new JdbcType();
    jdbcType.setCacheName("Sample");
    jdbcType.setDatabaseSchema("public");
    jdbcType.setKeyType("java.lang.Long");

    Collection<JdbcTypeField> keys = new ArrayList<JdbcTypeField>();
    keys.add(new JdbcTypeField(Types.BIGINT, "id", long.class, "id"));
    jdbcType.setKeyFields(keys.toArray(new JdbcTypeField[keys.size()]));
    Collection<JdbcTypeField> vals = new ArrayList<JdbcTypeField>();

    jdbcType.setDatabaseTable("sample");
    jdbcType.setValueType("com.nmf.SampleModel");

    vals.add(new JdbcTypeField(Types.BIGINT, "id", long.class, "id"));
    vals.add(new JdbcTypeField(Types.VARCHAR, "name", String.class, "name"));

    jdbcType.setValueFields(vals.toArray(new JdbcTypeField[vals.size()]));

    jdbcTypes.add(jdbcType);

    ((CacheJdbcPojoStoreFactory)cacheConfiguration.getCacheStoreFactory()).setTypes(jdbcTypes.toArray(new JdbcType[jdbcTypes.size()]));


    IgniteConfiguration icfg = new IgniteConfiguration();
    icfg.setCacheConfiguration(cacheConfiguration);

    Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(icfg);
```

SampleModel:

```
public class SampleModel implements Serializable {
private long id;
private String Name;

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return Name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    Name = name;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof SampleModel)) return false;

    SampleModel that = (SampleModel) o;

    return id == that.id;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return (int) (id ^ (id >>> 32));
}
```

}

Client Code:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(r -> new Thread(r, "worker"));


    CacheConfiguration cacheConfiguration = new CacheConfiguration();

    cacheConfiguration.setName("Sample");
    cacheConfiguration.setCacheMode(CacheMode.REPLICATED);
    cacheConfiguration.setAtomicityMode(CacheAtomicityMode.ATOMIC);
    cacheConfiguration.setRebalanceMode(CacheRebalanceMode.ASYNC);
    cacheConfiguration.setWriteSynchronizationMode(CacheWriteSynchronizationMode.FULL_SYNC);
    cacheConfiguration.setBackups(0);
    cacheConfiguration.setCopyOnRead(true);
    cacheConfiguration.setStoreKeepBinary(false);

    IgniteConfiguration icfg = new IgniteConfiguration();
    icfg.setCacheConfiguration(cacheConfiguration);

    icfg.setClientMode(true);

    final Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(icfg);

    ignite.events().localListen(new IgnitePredicate<Event>() {
        public boolean apply(Event event) {
            if (event.type() == EVT_CLIENT_NODE_RECONNECTED) {
                System.out.println("Reconnected");

                executor.submit(()-> {
                    IgniteCache<Long, SampleModel> cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache("Sample");

                    System.out.println("Got the cache");

                    SampleModel model = cache.get(1L);

                    System.out.println(model.getName());
                });
            }

            return true;
        }
    }, EVT_CLIENT_NODE_RECONNECTED);

    IgniteCache<Long, SampleModel> cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache("Sample");

    SampleModel model = cache.get(1L);

    System.out.println(model.getName());
```

Error log on Client:

```
    SEVERE: Failed to reinitialize local partitions (preloading will be stopped): GridDhtPartitionExchangeId [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=2, minorTopVer=1], nodeId=dea5f59b, evt=DISCOVERY_CUSTOM_EVT]
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to start component: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Failed to initialize cache store (data source is not provided).
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.startLifecycleAware(IgniteUtils.java:8726)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.createCache(GridCacheProcessor.java:1486)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.prepareCacheStart(GridCacheProcessor.java:1931)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.prepareCacheStart(GridCacheProcessor.java:1833)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheAffinitySharedManager.onCacheChangeRequest(CacheAffinitySharedManager.java:379)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.onCacheChangeRequest(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:688)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.init(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:529)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$ExchangeWorker.body(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:1806)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:110)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Failed to initialize cache store (data source is not provided).
    at org.apache.ignite.cache.store.jdbc.CacheAbstractJdbcStore.start(CacheAbstractJdbcStore.java:298)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.startLifecycleAware(IgniteUtils.java:8722)
    ... 9 more

July 25, 2017 12:58:38 PM org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger error
SEVERE: Failed to wait for completion of partition map exchange (preloading will not start): GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture [dummy=false, forcePreload=false, reassign=false, discoEvt=DiscoveryCustomEvent [customMsg=null, affTopVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=2, minorTopVer=1], super=DiscoveryEvent [evtNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=dea5f59b-bdda-47a1-b31d-1ecb08fc746f, addrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, 127.0.0.1, 192.168.224.1, 192.168.6.15, 192.168.80.1, 2001:0:9d38:90d7:c83:fac:98d7:5fc1], sockAddrs=[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:0, /127.0.0.1:0, Ares-W11/169.254.194.93:0, /2001:0:9d38:90d7:c83:fac:98d7:5fc1:0, /192.168.6.15:0, windows10.microdone.cn/192.168.224.1:0, /192.168.80.1:0], discPort=0, order=2, intOrder=0, lastExchangeTime=1500958697559, loc=true, ver=2.0.0#20170430-sha1:d4eef3c6, isClient=true], topVer=2, nodeId8=dea5f59b, msg=null, type=DISCOVERY_CUSTOM_EVT, tstamp=1500958718133]], crd=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=247d2926-010d-429b-aef2-97a18fbb3b5d, addrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, 127.0.0.1, 192.168.224.1, 192.168.6.15, 192.168.80.1, 2001:0:9d38:90d7:c83:fac:98d7:5fc1], sockAddrs=[/192.168.6.15:47500, /2001:0:9d38:90d7:c83:fac:98d7:5fc1:47500, windows10.microdone.cn/192.168.224.1:47500, /192.168.80.1:47500, Ares-W11/169.254.194.93:47500, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:47500, /127.0.0.1:47500], discPort=47500, order=1, intOrder=1, lastExchangeTime=1500958718083, loc=false, ver=2.0.0#20170430-sha1:d4eef3c6, isClient=false], exchId=GridDhtPartitionExchangeId [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=2, minorTopVer=1], nodeId=dea5f59b, evt=DISCOVERY_CUSTOM_EVT], added=true, initFut=GridFutureAdapter [ignoreInterrupts=false, state=DONE, res=false, hash=842035444], init=false, lastVer=null, partReleaseFut=null, affChangeMsg=null, skipPreload=true, clientOnlyExchange=false, initTs=1500958718133, centralizedAff=false, changeGlobalStateE=null, exchangeOnChangeGlobalState=false, forcedRebFut=null, evtLatch=0, remaining=[247d2926-010d-429b-aef2-97a18fbb3b5d], srvNodes=[TcpDiscoveryNode [id=247d2926-010d-429b-aef2-97a18fbb3b5d, addrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, 127.0.0.1, 192.168.224.1, 192.168.6.15, 192.168.80.1, 2001:0:9d38:90d7:c83:fac:98d7:5fc1], sockAddrs=[/192.168.6.15:47500, /2001:0:9d38:90d7:c83:fac:98d7:5fc1:47500, windows10.microdone.cn/192.168.224.1:47500, /192.168.80.1:47500, Ares-W11/169.254.194.93:47500, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:47500, /127.0.0.1:47500], discPort=47500, order=1, intOrder=1, lastExchangeTime=1500958718083, loc=false, ver=2.0.0#20170430-sha1:d4eef3c6, isClient=false]], super=GridFutureAdapter [ignoreInterrupts=false, state=DONE, res=class o.a.i.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to start component: class o.a.i.IgniteException: Failed to initialize cache store (data source is not provided)., hash=1281081640]]
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to start component: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Failed to initialize cache store (data source is not provided).
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.startLifecycleAware(IgniteUtils.java:8726)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.createCache(GridCacheProcessor.java:1486)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.prepareCacheStart(GridCacheProcessor.java:1931)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.prepareCacheStart(GridCacheProcessor.java:1833)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheAffinitySharedManager.onCacheChangeRequest(CacheAffinitySharedManager.java:379)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.onCacheChangeRequest(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:688)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.init(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:529)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$ExchangeWorker.body(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:1806)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:110)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Failed to initialize cache store (data source is not provided).
    at org.apache.ignite.cache.store.jdbc.CacheAbstractJdbcStore.start(CacheAbstractJdbcStore.java:298)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.startLifecycleAware(IgniteUtils.java:8722)
    ... 9 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Only server nodes store caches(except of Local caches), so, when you restarted server node, this cache was stopped. The problem here is that client node was reconnected to the cluster, but not joined it as new node. That's why cache was not created again.

I think it's wrong behavior and cache should be recreated at client reconnecting.
I've created an [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-5789) for that.

As a workaround, you can use Ignite.GetOrCreateCache("Sample") method instead of Ignite.GetCache("Sample")

Comment: thanks for your reply, seems it will be hang when calling the code `Ignite.GetOrCreateCache("Sample") `,  update the question by adding more error log.

Comment: Please share also CacheConfiguration

Comment: Yes, also update the CacheConfiguration in the question description.

Comment: Why did you configure KeepBinaryInStore = true? You don't have configured cacheStore

Comment: Sorry, Im not expert on Ignite, may I know how to set configured cacheStore?

Comment: First of all, are you sure that you need persistence? If not, just remove KeepBinaryInStore = true. If you need it, check this doc: https://apacheignite-net.readme.io/v2.0/docs/persistent-store

Comment: or, you can find an example of xml config for cache store here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44819513/org-apache-ignite-ignitecheckedexception-cannot-enable-write-through/44819881#44819881

Comment: the cache mode is Replicated, so the it is stored on the server not the client, the client is only to get the cache instead of create.

Comment: The cache store on the client is required for TRANSACTIONAL caches. For ATOMIC caches (this is the default mode), it's not needed. So, if you use Atomic cache, just delete KeepBinaryInStore = true

Comment: OK, even remove KeepBinaryInStore = true, the issue is still there, BTW everything works if server is not started.

Comment: OK, then provide config from server too

Comment: Thanks for your help and patience, already updated the cache configuration on the server side.

Comment: Hi Evgenii, do you have any further suggestion or finding?

Comment: have you tried to delete 
cacheConfiguration.setStoreKeepBinary(true); from server configuration too?

Comment: The server uses  cacheConfiguration.setStoreKeepBinary(true), since it has persistent store.

Comment: It seems that we cannot remove the `cacheConfiguration.setStoreKeepBinary(true)` on server side.

Comment: Hi Sir, im really stuck by this issue, could you please help me out, I can provide any further information if needed.

Comment: I have paste the whole code for both client and server on the question description, and remove `cacheConfiguration.setStoreKeepBinary(true)` on both sides.

Answer (score 0):

Are you still having issues where Ignite.GetOrCreateCache("Sample") hangs? Make sure you aren't making that call from a thread in the System Pool. I was listening for the EVT_CLIENT_NODE_RECONNECTED event and calling Ignite.GetOrCreateCache("Sample") when I ran into a similar issue. For more information, see the answer to this question: [Closures stuck in 2.0 when try to add an element into the queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43891757/closures-stuck-in-2-0-when-try-to-add-an-element-into-the-queue)

Comment: thanks for your answer, but no lucky, I start  a new tread when calling `Ignite.GetOrCreateCache("Sample")`

Comment: In your client code it doesn't look like you are using a separate thread pool. Try something like this:
    `ignite.compute().withExecutor("my-thread-pool").runAsync(() -> {
                            Ignite.GetOrCreateCache("Sample");
                        });`

Don't forget to set up your custom "my-thread-pool" in the Ignite configuration.