# IgniteCheckedException: Failed to perform cache operation (cache is stopped)

Tags: .net, ignite

Every now and then, I see the following exception which I do not understand.
It happens when not all nodes of a cluster are online. I'm not aware that a cache can be started or stopped (Windows, C#, Ignite Version 2.4). The cluster is active when I receive that error and persistency is enabled.

```
 JavaException: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to perform cache operation (cache is stopped): MyCacheName
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.utils.PlatformUtils.unwrapQueryException(PlatformUtils.java:519)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.cache.PlatformCache.runFieldsQuery(PlatformCache.java:1240)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.cache.PlatformCache.processInStreamOutObject(PlatformCache.java:877)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.PlatformTargetProxyImpl.inStreamOutObject(PlatformTargetProxyImpl.java:79)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: class org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheStoppedException: Failed to perform cache operation (cache is stopped): MyCacheName
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheGateway.enter(GridCacheGateway.java:164)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GatewayProtectedCacheProxy.onEnter(GatewayProtectedCacheProxy.java:1684)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GatewayProtectedCacheProxy.query(GatewayProtectedCacheProxy.java:365)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.cache.PlatformCache.runFieldsQuery(PlatformCache.java:1234)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheStoppedException: Failed to perform cache operation (cache is stopped): MyCacheName
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: Do you run queries from client node? In logs should be "cache stopped" message, check what happened before cache stopping. Please attach log snippet from that node.

Comment: It is no client node. Unfortunately I cannot purposely reproduce the error.

Answer (score 1):

Posible that you have the same problem as here:

[Ignite Cache Reconnection Issue (Cache is stopped)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46053089/ignite-cache-reconnection-issue-cache-is-stopped)

If your case is the like in this issue:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-5789

then as workaround you can try to restart the client node.