# Can not start/stop cache within lock or transaction with DataStorageConfiguration

Tags: ignite

I have one server node and one client node. In DataStorageConfiguration ,persistent is enabled.
I restarted my server node and trying to perform the operations on cache. I am getting below exceptions. This exception is if I use DataStorageConfiguration.

Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Cannot start/stop cache within lock or transaction. [cacheName=, operation=dynamicStartCache]
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.checkEmptyTransactionsEx(GridCacheProcessor.java:4879)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.dynamicStartCache(GridCacheProcessor.java:3460)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.dynamicStartCache(GridCacheProcessor.java:3404)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.publicJCache(GridCacheProcessor.java:4416)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.publicJCache(GridCacheProcessor.java:4387)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GatewayProtectedCacheProxy.checkProxyIsValid(GatewayProtectedCacheProxy.java:1602)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GatewayProtectedCacheProxy.onEnter(GatewayProtectedCacheProxy.java:1619)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GatewayProtectedCacheProxy.put(GatewayProtectedCacheProxy.java:853)

Can you please help?

Answer (score 1):

[Ignite Cache Reconnection Issue (Cache is stopped)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46053089/ignite-cache-reconnection-issue-cache-is-stopped)

I have refereed above link and liten the reconnect event and then call ignite.getOrCreateCache(spaCacheName);

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should not use e.g. `getOrCreateCache` within a started transaction. Create all of your caches before starting a transaction. I think it's pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: my caches are created before starting transaction